# angular conditional title with static text before expression

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to have `title` conditionally but not sure `how i can add some static text with else expression`

**In my code,** both `myTooltip` and `displayName` are `angular expressions`. This work fine.

However, what if i want to append `static text i.e. Mr before displayName.` how can i do that?

```
title="{{(dataAvaialble ? myTooltip : displayName)}}"
```

I could wrote like this but it gives error

```
title="{{(dataAvaialble ? myTooltip : 'Mr' displayName)}}"
```

Comment: you can create a function and call it in ng-attr-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work:

```
ng-attr-title="{{ dataAvaialble ? myTooltip : 'Mr' + displayName }}
```